# UnityEngine.XR.WSA.WorldManager namespace not found, where does it reside now?

Tags: unity-game-engine, uwp, augmented-reality, hololens, windows-mixed-reality

UnityEngine.XR.WSA.WorldManager is obsolete.

What is the up to date alternative for

`UnityEngine.XR.WSA.WorldManager.GetNativeISpatialCoordinateSystemPtr();`

or has WorldManager moved home?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for built-in XR is removed in the latest Unity version. The [WinRT API](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/windowsstore-scripts.html), such as [Windows.Perception.Spatial.SpatialLocator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Perception.Spatial.SpatialLocator?view=winrt-19041) is the alternative for it. For your case, you can use `var spatialCoordinateSystem = SpatialLocator.GetDefault().CreateStationaryFrameOfReferenceAtCurrentLocation().CoordinateSystem;` to create a coordinate system with the origin placed at the device's position as the app is launched.